# Making a login screen using OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop, object, authentication, error-handling

i'm a beginner in PHP and i'm trying to make a login screen using PHP ... but i always get this error

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function login() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\public\admin\login.php on line 12

Here's my code :

Login.php :

```
<?php
require_once("../../includes/database.php");    
require_once("../../includes/user.php");    
require_once("../../includes/functions.php");
require_once("../../includes/session.php");
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $obj = User::auth();
    if($obj){
        $session->login($obj);
        redirect_to("index.php");
    } else {
        $message= "USER NOT FOUND.";
    }
    echo '<p id="message">';
    echo output_message($message); 
    echo "</p>";

}
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets/main.css">     
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
        <h3>Please Login</h3>
        <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <p><label for="username">Username :</label><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/></p>
            <p><label for="password">Password :</label><input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password"/></p>  
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
        </form>            

    </div>

</body>
```

session.php

```
<?php
require_once("database.php");   
require_once("user.php");   
require_once("functions.php");  
?>

<?php   
class Session{
    private $logged = false;
    public $user_id;

    function __construct(){
        session_start();
        if($this->is_logged()){
            redirect_to("index.php");
        } else {
            $message = "Try Again!";
        }
    }

    public function is_logged(){
        return $logged;
    }

    public function login($user){
        if($user){
            $this->user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user->id ;
            $this->logged = true ;
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        unset($_SESSION["user_id"]);
        unset($this->user_id);
        redirect_to("login.php");
    }
}

?>
```

user.php

```
<?php
require_once("database.php");
require_once("session.php");

class User {

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $first_name;
    public $last_name;

    public static function find_all(){
        global $db;
        $object = new self;         
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
        $result = $db->add_query($query);
        $object = array();
        while($found = $db->fetch_array($result)){
            $object[] = self::resolve_data($found);
        }
        return $object;
    }

    public static function find_by_id($id){
        global $db;
        $object = new self;
        $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id={$id}";
        $result = $db->add_query($query);
        $found = $db->fetch_array($result);
        $object = self::resolve_data($found);
        return $object;
    }

    public static function auth(){
        global $db;
        global $session;
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM users 
                    WHERE username = '{$username}' AND password = '{$password}' LIMIT                            1";

        $result = $db->add_query($query);
        if($data = $db->fetch_array($result)){
            $obj = self::find_by_id($data["id"]);
            return $obj;
        } else {
            $message="user not found.";
        }
    }

    private static function resolve_data($arr){
       $object = new self;
       $object->id = $arr["id"];
       $object->username = $arr["username"];
       $object->password = $arr["password"];
       $object->first_name = $arr["first_name"];
       $object->last_name = $arr["last_name"];
       return $object;


    }

}



  ?>
```

database.php

```
  <?php

class Database{
    private $connection ;

    function __construct(){
        $this->open_connection();
    }

    public function open_connection(){
        $this->connection = mysql_connect("localhost" , "root" , "smokn");
        if(!$this->connection){
            die("Error while opening connection: " . mysql_error() );
        } else {
            $db_select = mysql_select_db("photo_gallery" , $this->connection);
            if(!$db_select){
                die("Error while selecting DB: " . mysql_error() );
            }
        }
    }

    public function close_connection(){
        if(isset($this->connection)){
            mysql_close($this->connection);
            unset($this->connection);
        }
    }

    public function add_query($query){
        $result = mysql_query($query , $this->connection);
        if(!$result){
            die("Error while adding query: " . mysql_error());
        } else { 
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function fetch_array($result){
        return mysql_fetch_array($result);
    }

    public function escape_value ($value){          
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
        return $value;
    }

    public function num_rows ($result){
        return mysql_num_rows($result);
    }

    public function inserted_id(){
        return mysql_insert_id($this->connection);
    }

    public function affected_rows(){
        return mysql_affected_rows($this->connection);
    }

}

$db = new Database() ;

    ?>
```

This is really frustrating. I spent like 2 hours trying to figure it out but had no luck..

Comment: do you have a line number for that error?

Comment: ah sorry. I'll edit the error message above . Thanks.

Comment: Where are you instantiating $session?

Comment: Is that **your** code? Why don't you instantiate the `$session` object anywhere?

Comment: It's a tutorial in lynda.com videos... i'm following along..
and silly me.. I totally forgot to instantiate Session class !..
Sorry for being so noobish guys :).. thanks again :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
$session->login($obj);
```

`$session` has not been instantiated, and is therefore not an object (as the error states). You will need to instantiate it like this:

```
$session = new Session();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're missing `$session;`

find

```
    public function logout(){
        unset($_SESSION["user_id"]);
        unset($this->user_id);
        redirect_to("login.php");
    }
}
```

and put this after

```
$session = new Session();
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Login.php`, just after you require your class files; add the line:

```
$session = new Session;
```

to get an instance of your class.